# Htaccess rewrite (insert characters)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an important temporary rewrite need. I need to rewrite:

```
http://www.mysite.com/product_info?products_id=23077
```

to:

```
http://www.mysite.com/product_info.php?products_id=23077
```

I thought this should work:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^product_info\?(.*)$ product_info.php\?products_id=23077
```

But it does not work. I get an error:

> The requested URL /product_info was not found on this server

Obviously 23077 could be any number.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested, but something like this should work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(product_info)\?(products_id=23077)/?$  http://www.mysite.com/$1.php?$2 [NC]
```